# Application-level scheduling

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

As far as I know Windows uses a round-robin scheduler which distributes time slices to each ruanable thread.

This means that if an application/process has multiple threads it gets an larger amount of the computational resources than other application with fewer threads.

Now one could think of a operating system scheduler that assigns an equal amount of the compuational resources to each application. And this partition is distributed among all threads of this application. The result would be that no application could affect other applications just because it has more threads.

Now my questions:

- How is such scheduling called? I need a term so I can search for research papers regarding such scheduling.
- Do operating systems exist which uses such scheduling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's some variation of ["fair" scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair-share_scheduling).

I expect that you will need to use synonyms for "application", for example they may be called "tasks" or "processes" instead.

Comment: Do you know an operating system or kernel implementation which uses fair scheduling on an application level?

Comment: @chris - No I don't. I understand the reason for fairness between users on a multi-user system. Why fairness between applications on a single-user system? On a single-user system, the user can tweak the scheduling (the relative priorities) of their own applications.